# Replicating a 'vlookup' in Microsoft Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, power-automate, flow

I'm looking for some help with a couple of lists I'm working with. Essentially I have a main list called 'Risk Events' which has an automatically generated ID for each item, and then another list called 'Comments' which uses a lookup to pull in ID, and has associated comments for each item.

What I would like is whenever comments are updated, they automatically pull back through to the 'Risk Events' form under the original ID. The current flow won't work to achieve this, when I select the custom ID from my comments (called Risk ID) in the Get Item on my flow, it gives me the following error:

[image]

This is my flow currently:

[image]

[image]

Would really appreciate any help in getting this sorted! Thanks for the support :)

Comment: I think you have to use "ID" instead of "Risk ID" in "Get item" action if you are fetching the item details from same list.

Comment: What @Ganesh said is correct. That should solve your issue. Also is there some reason you're not using the OOB Comments feature on Modern lists?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following flow:

[image]

[image]

Explanation: The list3 corresponds to “Risk Events", list4 corresponds to "Comments", here if I create or modify an item, then if ID in list3 is equal to this "Risk ID", the column "Comment1" in list3 will be updated to the value in "Comment4" in list4. What's more, you need to pay attention that in picture2, the ID is from "Get items" not "When an item is created or modified".

Fine, as a result, this flow runs successfully:
[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Hi, Benwdj. Is this answer helpful for you? Please feel free to reply.